# Align background image to the left centered vertically

Tags: css, background-image

I have a background image that I would like centered vertically within an element, but aligned to the left of the element. what's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Pekka, you're right. can you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `background-position` CSS property, in this case

```
background-position: left center;
```

W3C Reference: [Colors and backgrounds](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background-properties)